# How can I use pyqt4 with current python and spyder version?

Tags: python, pyqt, anaconda, spyder

for some python programming I do for work I'd like to use pyqt4. I also use Anaconda and the Spyder IDE.

To downgrade pyqt from 5 to 4 I created a new environment within Anaconda. The problem is that everytime I install Spyder in this environment the pyqt version is being upgraded to 5 again.

Is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) You need to create your environment (called `spy-pyqt4` in this case) with the following command

`conda create -n spy-pyqt4 spyder=3.2.8 pyqt=4`

Spyder **3.2.8** was our last version to support PyQt4.

Comment: For someone who's really new into this (like me) this was very helpful! I have PyQt4 within Spyder now =) Thanks alot Sir!

Comment: Cool, that's good to know - I was not that lucky years ago when I tried spyder with QT4